# limit div height

Tags: html, css

Can some one please explain why when I tell a div that:

- it's height is 500px and it's max height is also 500px,
- overflow if he needs (auto).

when put elements dynamically inside the div it'll grow to the size it needs, regard my limits, and the entire page will scroll not the div.

why? how to fix?

Ok, sorry for the minimal details, I just got it, if using display: inline-table, it ignores all this stuff I wrote that don't work...
thanks

Comment: `max-height` isn't working for you?

Comment: Please set up a jsFiddle. It's quite hard to understand your problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's `overflow: auto` and not `overflow: visible` (which is default)?

Comment: What browser. Can you put together a demo? You should by now know we need more info to be able to help you.

Comment: if you use *over*flow, then the height won't extend. Sounds fair, doesn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following seems to work just fine for me. See a demo here: http://jsbin.com/iqigen/5/edit

```
<style>
  #box {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
</style>
<div id="box"></div>
```

When the collective height of the nested elements exceeds that of the parent, the parent will engage in overflowing. When the content overflows, a scrollbar will be shown on the parent element, obstructing any view of the child elements beyond the bounds of their container.

You can add several dynamic elements with the following:

```
var colors = [ '#F00', '#660', '#066' ];

setInterval( addElement, 1000 );

function addElement(){
  $("<p>", { text: new Date() })
    .css( 'background', colors[ Math.floor( Math.random() * colors.length ) ] )
    .appendTo( "#hello" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking based on wording. But if you're saying that the div doesn't grow and content goes past the div onto the background so the page scrolls while the div stays smaller than the content.

The reason that would happen is because you put a max-height: 500px; on your div. In doing this you're saying 'no matter what don't go larger than 500px. If you set a min-height to 500px then it would always be 500px unless you needed it to be larger to fit content.

Once again I apologize if this isn't exactly what you're asking.

Comment: He clearly says, _"it'll grow to the size it needs"_, so I'm not sure how your answer is relevant.

Comment: @Sparky672: OP is stating nothing clearly at all. At least I won't stretch it that much an better respect the answerer trying to be helpful here. +1 therefore.

Comment: @hakre, So it's better to reward an answer to a question that states nothing clearly?  Assuming so, we won't even know which answers are relevant until we know what the OP is asking.